# Having trouble building AWS SDK JavaScript Version 3 library for browser JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, webpack, browser, sdk

I am trying to use webpack to build a library of modules from the AWS SDK (JavaScript Version 3) that are compatible with ***browser*** JavaScript.  In the library I need Cognito, S3 and DynamoDB modules.

I have used npm to install the following libraries:

```
@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity
@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb
@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb-streams
@aws-sdk/client-s3
```

Next, I installed webpack

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/main.js',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Get script src',
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js'),
    filename: 'aws-sdk-js-v3.js',
    library: "awssdk"
  },
  mode: 'production', //development
  target: 'web',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.m?js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

main.js

```js
import { CognitoIdentityClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity";
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { DynamoDBStreamsClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb-streams";
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

console.log(new CognitoIdentityClient({ region: 'us-east-1' }));
console.log(new DynamoDBClient({ region: 'us-east-1' }));
console.log(new DynamoDBStreamsClient({ region: 'us-east-1' }));
console.log(new S3Client({ region: 'us-east-1' }));
```

`npm run build` creates aws-sdk-js-v3.js as expected.

I added the following tags to the head of index.html:

```
<script type="module" defer="defer" src="js/aws-sdk-js-v3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

When I load index.html, I get an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument.` on the very first import call in main.js.

I can't figure out why the modules will not import.  I am wondering if the library was possibly not built correctly or something.  Does anyone see any mistakes in my process or something missing or wrong with webpack.config.js.

Comment: try add babel present env. https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/

Comment: I tried adding babel, rebuilt but still got the same error.  I will update webpack.config.js above with my changes.

Comment: `import` keyword only works inside modules and your `main.js` seems missing `type="module"`. There might be something else, but it is hard to say without seeing all the setup, so it would be helpful if you could provide as much as possible.

Comment: "type": "module" in package.json as @Shlang mention. [docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/) but i thought that they solved this 'problem' in webpack 5

Comment: add libraryTarget: 'umd', to output [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget)